# Unexpected results in multiplying array by scalar

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

From the "Just When I Thought I Was Gettin' The Hang Of Numpy" file...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.array((1650, 2300, 2560, 3710)) * 1000000
>>> y
array([ 1650000000, -1994967296, -1734967296,  -584967296])
```

My old math instructor would agree with the first result, but the others???

FWIW, running Python 3.6.3 on 64-bit Win 10, and also get (as expected)

```
>>> 2300 * 1000000
2300000000
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting this result, all my outputs agree with your old math instructor.. Can you provide your run environment?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Getting ```array([1650000000, 2300000000, 2560000000, 3710000000])```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that integers have a maximum value of 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647.

Your first value is smaller than that, but the other 3 are larger. Hence you get "looparound". Note that:

```
-1994967296 = -2147483648 + (2300000000 - 2147483647 - 1)
```

So basically you've gone to the maximum value (2147483647) added 1 to get to the the lowest (-2147483648) and then continued from there.

You can get around this by forcing 64-bit precision

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.array((1650, 2300, 2560, 3710), dtype='int64') * 1000000
>>> y
array([1650000000, 2300000000, 2560000000, 3710000000], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: It's not happening for me, is this due to python or numpy version issue?

Comment: On windows with python 2.7, I get `np.array((1650, 2300, 2560, 3710)).dtype == 'int32'`, i guess you get `'int64'` on your machine?

Comment: It's possible, getting ```int64``` on Linux.

Comment: @YilunZhang numpy uses C language `long` as default int type. I think OP's machine has `long` only 32-bit.

Comment: Is the C language "long" changeable from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Comment: @liliscent that makes sense to me. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by 32-bit integer overflow. If you want to handle all big integers, use `dtype=np.object`. Of course there will be some performance penalty:

```
y = np.array((1650, 2300, 2560, 3710),dtype=np.object) * 10000000000000
```

Comment: That approach did indeed produce the intended "magnified" array, but unfortunately, as an 'object' dtype (I suppose) I wasn't able to take the log of the array elements. But taking the logs in vectorized fashion (np.log(y)) worked fine when setting up y as dtype=int64.

Comment: It always depends on your need. `int64` will also overflow, but `object` will never. Try: `np.array((1650, 2300, 2560, 3710),dtype=np.int64) * 100000000000000000`, similar situations to your original question occur because of `int64` overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your values are looping around because they are bigger than the maximum int.

You can use int64 to get more range (will also use more memory):

```
y = np.array((1650, 2300, 2560, 3710), dtype=np.int64)
```

See all the available types [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html).